# Weird double loading image on simple html page

Tags: html, google-chrome, brave-browser

I am developing a website page on brave when I noticed unnecessary request were made to the server. So I have tried narrowing the case down to this demo over here to reproduce the weird behavior.

Ref: https://github.com/brave/brave-browser/issues/6863

### Expectation

A standard `<img src="..." />` tag should request the said resources **only once**.

### The problem

> **The page request the same URI twice.**

Each request you see on this image below returned 2 different image. Only the first one were rendered on the screen. Yet The second request do fetch another completely different image from the server.

[image: Annotation 2019-11-10 102409]

### The weird part

The problem **only happen** when the `<img>` tag is in between two heading / paragraph tag. And it will only happen when the first paragraph **has more than 4 word**. The problem does not happen if the first paragraph has fewer words. That is for me is weird. Yet, this situation is likely to happen on a regular web document.

### Reproducing

A simple web page should be able to reproduce the case.

```
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Images</title>
  <meta name="date.modified" content="Sun, 10 Nov 2019 03:01:15 GMT" />
</head>

<body>
  <p>0 1 2 3 4</p>
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/160/120" />
  <p>0</p>
</body>
```

### Brave version

I am using Brave is up to date
Version 0.70.123 Chromium: 78.0.3904.97 (Official Build) (64-bit)

PS: I hope this issue get solved quickly. Because it may cause large image to be loaded multiple times more than necessary.